# 70-persistent-net.rules not being honoured

Tags: networking, 18.04, udev

This is a PXE-install, which has previously been 14.04. I'm moving it to 18.04, and most things are OK, but for some reason, only one of the rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` (automatically generated by the preseed script) is being honoured.

`/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="40:8d:5c:5c:df:ce", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", NAME="ctrl1"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="68:05:ca:22:c6:0b", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", NAME="data1"
```

`/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto ctrl1
iface ctrl1 inet dhcp

auto data1
iface data1 inet static
    address    10.255.01.13
    netmask    255.255.255.240
    network    10.255.01.0
    broadcast  10.255.01.255
```

ifconfig output:

```
foo@bar:~# ifconfig
data1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet xx.xx.xx.xx  netmask 255.255.255.240  broadcast 10.255.1.255
        inet6 fe80::6a05:caff:fe22:c60b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 68:05:ca:22:c6:0b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 123  bytes 10749 (10.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 44  bytes 3772 (3.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 17  memory 0xdc040000-dc060000  

enp0s31f6: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet xx.xx.xx.xx  netmask 255.255.255.128  broadcast 192.168.166.255
        inet6 fe80::428d:5cff:fe5c:dfce  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 40:8d:5c:5c:df:ce  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 966  bytes 89471 (89.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 701  bytes 391743 (391.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xdc100000-dc120000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 697  bytes 57332 (57.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 697  bytes 57332 (57.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`data1` is OK, but `ctrl1` is not being set.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure SystemD actually honors the udev rules... I'd have to check, but I'm pretty sure you wouldn't be able to easily make it obey the Udev definitions you've stated since SystemD operates slightly differently...

Comment: Oh. That's interesting - there's all sorts of information out there on the interwebs about manually configuring the udev rules on 18.04. I'vs had a quick look at the SystemD stuff, and it looks promising. I'll have a further dig tomorrow, thanks.

Comment: I ran into the same issue today. Separating the rules into separate files fixed the issue.

Comment: @DennisMungai That's interesting, I will try this next time we need to rebuild, thanks.